# Rails aggregate query counting rows that satisfy certain conditions

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, aggregate-functions

Let's say that have a table called bets.  I want to run an aggregate sql query that counts rows satisfying certain conditions.  For example, I want to return a count of all bets won, all bets lost, etc.  I also want these counts to be grouped by several different columns.  I tried a few different queries, but not getting the results I'd expect.  For example:

```
Bet.select("user_id, event_id, bet_line_id, pick, COUNT(state = 'won') AS bets_won,
COUNT(state = 'lost') AS bets_lost, COUNT(state = 'pushed') AS bets_pushed").
group('user_id, event_id, bet_line_id, pick')
```

Just gives me the result of "1" for bets_won or bets_lost or bets_pushed for any of the records returned.  Using Rails 3.2 + postgres.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to pass `case` expression so it will return `bigint` value .

```
Bet.select("user_id, event_id, bet_line_id, pick, 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN state = 'won' then 1 ELSE null END) AS bets_won,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN state = 'lost' then 1 ELSE null END) AS bets_lost, 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN state = 'pushed' then 1 ELSE null END) AS bets_pushed").
 group('user_id, event_id, bet_line_id, pick')
```

Comment: Some explanation of why things like `COUNT(state = 'won')` don't work would be useful.

Comment: @muistooshort, I am not really sure, but I think the `expression` is evaluated as `string` so it returns `0`. if i am wrong please `edit`/`create-new`  answer and explain relevant explanation.  Thanks

Comment: `count(expr)` counts the rows where `expr` is not NULL but `a = b` will be TRUE or FALSE unless `a` or `b` is NULL.

Answer (score 2):

`count(expression)` is defined to count the ["number of input rows for which the value of `expression` is not null"](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE). The `state = 'won'` expression only evaluates to NULL only when `state is null`, otherwise it will be one of the boolean values TRUE or FALSE. The result is that `count(state = 'won')` is actually counting the number of rows where `state is not null` and that's not what you're trying to do.

You can use [Paritosh Piplewar's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23439023/479863). Another common approach is to use `sum` and `case`:

```
sum(case state when 'won'    then 1 else 0 end) as bets_won,
sum(case state when 'lost'   then 1 else 0 end) as bets_lost,
sum(case state when 'pushed' then 1 else 0 end) as bets_pushed
```